# Very tricky Power Query text extraction

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have two columns below where there are multiple “tenants” in one column and multiple “areas” in another. I want to extract all the “SA Majeste” and “PWGSC” entities and their corresponding areas such that my desired output is:

| Tenant | Areas |
| --- | --- |
| SA MAJESTE LA REINE (81001068) PWGSC | 6,776 |
| SA MAJESTE LA REINE (81001068) PWGSC | 6,174 |
| PWGSC (81000921) | 16,964 |
| PWGSC (81000732) | 9,438 |
| SA MAJESTE LA REINE ( 81001133) | 6,075 |

Based on this source table

| Tenant | Areas |
| --- | --- |
| THE CHEMICAL INSTITUTE OF CANADA - [10] RESIDENT DOCTORS OF Vacant SA MAJESTE LA REINE (81001068) PWGSC ^ | 0400D(3,643.00)-08/31/2025 0401B(7,453.00)-11/30/2023 0402(2,178.00)- CANADA - [11] 11/30/2026 0450(6,776.00) ^ |
| CRESTVIEW STRATEGY INC. SA MAJESTE LA REINE (81001068) PWGSC Vacant - [12] [13] ^ | 1100(4,748.00)-06/30/2030 1101(6,174.00)-11/30/2023 1105(1,715.00) ^ |
| PWGSC (81000921) KELLY SANTINI MANAGEMENT CORP. KELLY SANTINI [14] ^ | 2401(16,964.00)-09/30/2026 2402(14,535.00)-04/30/2026 2403(4,482.00)- ^ |
| PWGSC (81000732) ^ BELL CANADA (Office) | 1401(9,438.00)-02/29/2032 1402(29,711.00)-06/30/2030 ^ |
| Vacant SA MAJESTE LA REINE ( 81001133) ^ | 3000(11,925.00) 3001(6,075.00)-10/31/2024 ^ |

As can be seen, the SA Majeste or PWGSC entities are not always in second place. They could be in third, fourth or nth place. Thus, there is a pattern for extraction, but I had no luck figuring out the M formula for this extraction.

Unfortunately, all the data comes from a PDF online, so I have no control over how the data are structured…I’d have normalized the data to make the table analysis-friendly otherwise. Please help?

Comment: I would look at find() and mid()

Comment: Please provide input as text, methodology for transformation, and sample desired output.  Images don't help anyone.  I don't want to retype that to try and develop a methodology, and even if I did, the image is so unclear, I would not be able to.

Comment: Why do you post your data as a screenshot? Do you expect someone to manually type it in in order to help you? [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @horseyride My bad, hope I formatted the data correctly this time. Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Pardon my ignorance; I removed the screenshot and it's my first time making a table on stackoverflow

Comment: Still missing is sample desired output and explanation from input to output if not obvious

Comment: @horseyride I formulated my desired output table as well. I don't have an explanation as it is precisely the Power Query steps needed to go from the source table to my output table that has me stumped? Hope I'm not misunderstanding your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following produces something "close" to what you show.

- Split the Tenant column based on either the `-` or the word `Vacant`
- Collect the Areas by looking for a sequence of digits enclosed in parentheses, that may or may not start with space.
- Correlate the `SA MAJ..` string or the `PWGSC` string location with the same area location and return that area.
- Problem is that does not work as there does not seem to be a definitive, inclusive rule to also split `CRESTVIEW STRATEGY INC. SA MAJESTE LA REINE` into the two parts. I don't know if the string `INC.` would work, but that could be added if it does.

***Custom Function**
 Add below function as Custom Query (from blank) and rename it `fnRegexExtr`*

```
//see http://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/04/25/regex-in-power-bi-and-power-query-in-excel-with-java-script/
// and https://gist.github.com/Hugoberry/4948d96b45d6799c47b4b9fa1b08eadf

let   
    fx=(text,regex)=>
    Web.Page(
        "<script>
            var x='"&text&"';
            var y=new RegExp('"&regex&"','g');
            var b=x.match(y);
            document.write(b);
        </script>")[Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0}

in
    fx
```

***Main Code***

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table23"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Tenant", type text}, {"Areas", type text}}),

//Extract relevant Tenant
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Tenants", each Text.Replace(
            fnRegexExtr([Tenant], "(SA MAJESTE.*?(?=\\s*\\())|(\\(\\s*\\d+\\))|(PWGSC)"),","," "), type text),

//Extract relevant area
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Area", each 
        let 
            normalizeVacant = Text.Replace([Tenant],"Vacant","-x-"),
            split = List.RemoveItems(Text.Split(normalizeVacant,"-"),{""}),
            areas = List.Transform(
                        Text.Split(
                            fnRegexExtr([Areas],"\\([^)]+\\)"),"),"), 
                        each Number.From(Text.Remove(_,{")","("}))),
            tenant = List.Select(split, each Text.Contains(_,"SA MAJESTE") or Text.Contains(_,"PWGSC")),
            POStenant = List.PositionOf(split, tenant{0}),
            area =  areas{POStenant}
            
        in 
          area, Int64.Type),
    
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Tenant", "Areas"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

***Result from above***
[image]

The following code shows exactly what you show in your example. It arbitrarily decides to add one (1) to the area selection if the split that contains the `SA MAJ...` is not at the beginning of the text string.

This does not seem very robust to me, but maybe it will be good enough.

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table23"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Tenant", type text}, {"Areas", type text}}),

//Extract relevant Tenant
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Tenants", each Text.Replace(
            fnRegexExtr([Tenant], "(SA MAJESTE.*?(?=\\s*\\())|(\\(\\s*\\d+\\))|(PWGSC)"),","," "), type text),

//Extract relevant area
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Area", each 
        let 
            normalizeVacant = Text.Replace([Tenant],"Vacant","-x-"),
            split = List.RemoveItems(Text.Split(normalizeVacant,"-"),{""}),
            areas = List.Transform(
                        Text.Split(
                            fnRegexExtr([Areas],"\\([^)]+\\)"),"),"), 
                        each Number.From(Text.Remove(_,{")","("}))),
            tenant = List.Select(split, each Text.Contains(_,"SA MAJESTE") or Text.Contains(_,"PWGSC")){0},
            POS = List.PositionOf(split, tenant),
            POStenant = if Text.StartsWith(Text.Trim(tenant),"SA MAJ") or Text.StartsWith(Text.Trim(tenant),"PWGSC")
                            then POS else POS+1 ,
            area =  areas{POStenant}
            
        in 
            area, Int64.Type),
    
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Tenant", "Areas"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted and thanks! Regarding your point, "Split the Tenant column based on either the - or the word Vacant," it just so happened that many SA MAJ or PWGSC tenants have the word Vacant before them in this particular dataset. 

The text before them is technically random and could be anything. In that case, can we remove the normalizeVacant variable/line and simply start with:

split = List.RemoveItems(Text.Split(" ","-"),{""}), ? 

Sorry, I'm very new to M code and might not know what I'm doing...

Comment: @stack91 What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Changing "Vacant" to " " led to multiple errors (may I use a screenshot this time? https://imgur.com/a/c1739QU ). But technically, the text appearing before PWGSC or SA MAJ is random and "Vacant" may not produce accurate results...is there a more "universal" solution?

Comment: @stack91 *Changing "Vacant" to " " led to multiple errors* Then I think you have answered your question, which is probably represents [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is your real problem?

Comment: The problem would be, what if the word before SA MAJ or PWGSC isn't "Vacant," but all kinds of random words like "Ltd.," "Inc.," "ABC.," "XYZ.," etc. In this case, how can I modify your code to make it work properly? We got "lucky" with this stacking plan in that the word before PWG/SA MAJ is mostly "Vacant," but in most stacking plans, the word preceding PWG/SA MAJ can be anything. Does that make sense?

Comment: @stack91 In your `Row 2 Tenant`, the word preceding `SA` is not `Vacant` and the correct result is still output for both `Tenant` and `Area` so no, what you write does not make sense to me. Seems to me it would be simpler if you just provided a data sample that doesn't work properly **as TEXT**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254488/discussion-between-stack91-and-ron-rosenfeld).